# i got this exception when i am using java reflection api

Tags: java

i got this exception when i am using java reflection api

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:37)
 at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:18)
 at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:357)
```

Code:

```
    Field fieldlist[] = TestValue.class.getDeclaredFields();
    String result="";
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < fieldlist.length; i++) {
            Field fld = fieldlist[i];
            result += "name = " + fld.getName() + "\n";
            fld.setAccessible(true);
            result += "value = " + fld.get(this)+ "\n";
            System.out.println("Result----->"+result);
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You are using a IllegalArgument, please provide some more Code

Comment: What's the code causing the exception to be thrown?

Comment: Could you post your code please?  And the class you're trying to use through reflection.  This looks like you're passing an instance of the wrong class to a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing but, ... the Field is for a type which is not the same as the object you are passing.

EDIT: You are getting the fields of TestClass and using them to lookup the current object.

Instead you can write the following to lookup the field of the class for *this*

```
Field fieldlist[] = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
```

Comment: +1 - this is consistent with the javadoc.  OP - read the javadoc!